# Backbone Models: defaults based on a condition

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I'm pretty new to BackboneJS, looking for some help in the defaulting an attribute based on a condition
How can I default name to TEST based on a condition that is only if model.attribute = 'xyz' in Backbone models.

```
defaults: function() {
  return {
   name: 'TEST'
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `defaults` when you extend a Backbone model so you don't really have access to any instance attributes there.

If the default values you want to change depend on instance modal attributes set on instatiation (i.e `new MyModel({foo:"bar"})`) when you'd be better of setting an `initialize()` callback when extending your model.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    // I have access to this.attributes here
  }
});
```

Comment: Notice that `defaults` is a function in the question. So your first sentence is wrong. `this.attributes` is empty when accessed in the `defaults` function because attributes are in the process of being set, hence the `defaults` function being called.

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks all for your help.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I think there's nothing wrong with what I've said. Instance attributes haven't been populated at the time the `defaults` is evaled through Underscore's `result()`

Comment: _"when you extend a Backbone model"_, written as if the code runs only when extending the model class, which is false since it's a function that is called each time a model is instantiated. You do have access to the instance `attributes` hash, but it is empty at that point. What you don't have access to is the passed attributes (`new MyModel({foo:"bar"})`) because the `defaults` function receives no parameters.

Comment: I did upvote you though, that is just nitpicking on my part ;)